# How to calculate gaussian integal

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics, definite-integrals

we know that gaussian kernel is defined by

$K_\sigma(x-y)=\exp\frac{-\|x-y\|^2}{2\sigma^2}$

I want to calculate integral of this function:

$$H= \int K_\sigma(x−y)\cdot f(y)dx=f(y)\int K_\sigma(x−y)\,dx$$

where $f(y)$ is function of $y$. So my solution is

$$H=f(y)\cdot\frac {1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}}$$

Is it correct? If it is not correct. Can you help me edit it?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to calculate the integral, the following formula(from the Normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ in Probability) is needed:

$
\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-x^2/2}dx=\sqrt{2\pi}
$

We just need to calculate $\int_\mathbb{R} K_{\sigma}(x-y)dx$.

In fact, $\int_\mathbb{R} K_{\sigma}(x-y)dx=\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-(x-y)^2/2\sigma^2}dx=\sigma\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-t^2/2}dt=\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}$, in which the change of variable $t=(x-y)/\sigma$ is applied.

Hence we get $H=\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}f(y)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are correct. Besides, if kernel K function has property which is ∫Kσ(x)dx=1. So the result only is H=f(y) in this case.